# Filling a list with divided value

Tags: python, list, modulo

I'm looking for a way to divide a number which represents seconds passed (e.g. 11000) by 3600 to make it full hour and create a list like this:

`['3600','3600','3600','200']`

I know that this task is quite simple with basic math operations but I'm curious if there is more 'pythonic' way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, its quite simple in the pythonic way. Try this.

```
elapsed = 11000
split_list = ["3600"] * (elapsed // 3600) + [str(elapsed % 3600)]
```

In simple words, populate the fixed list and then append the difference.

Answer (score -1):

**You may try this  :-**

```
num = 11000//3600
times = []
for i in range(num):
    times. append("3600")
times. append(str(11000%3600))
print(times)
```